# Finding the Median of Distribution Function

Tags: probability-distributions

Let a distribution function be defined as the following:

$$F(x) = \begin{cases}
      1 - \dfrac{16}{x^2} & x\geq 4 \\
      0 & x<4   
\end{cases}$$

I was hoping for some confirmation on the median I calculated. I am very new to this material and do not have a lot of examples to work from. What I did was the following:

$$\left(1-\dfrac{16}{m^2}\right) - \left(1-\dfrac{16}{4^2}\right) = 0.5$$

Where $m$ is the median. I solved to get $m = \sqrt{32}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Median of distribution is a point $x$ such that

$$P(X \le x) = P(X \ge x)$$
$$\implies P( X \le x) = 0.5$$
$$\implies F_X(x) = 0.5$$

Edit: Since the given distribution given is continuous, we don't have to worry about $P(X=x)$. If it were a discrete distribution, we would have to adjust accordingly for the value of $P(X=x)$. In particular, if $X$ is a discrete RV,

$$P(X \le x) = P(X < x) + P(X=x)$$